# Get all the values of all jtextfields in a panel

Tags: java, jtextfield

All textfields in a panel have document listener. It adds all the value in all textfields, and settext it to another textfield which is in the other panel for the sum.

My problem is that I have 74 textfields, how can i check all of its value by using for loop? I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the code below. The gist of it is in the comments.

Cheers!

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class IterateOverJTextField {

    private static void iterateOverJTextFields(Container container) {
        // You have to call getComponents in order to access the
        // container's children.
        // Then you have to check the type of the component. 
        // In your case you're looking for JTextField. 
        // Then, you do what you want...
        // Old-style
        for (Component component : container.getComponents()) {
            if (component instanceof JTextField) {
                System.out.println(((JTextField) component).getText());
            }
        }

        // New-style with Stream
        Stream.of(container.getComponents())
              .filter(c -> c instanceof JTextField)
              .map(c -> ((JTextField) c).getText())
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JTextField("text 1"));
        panel.add(new JTextField("text 2"));
        panel.add(new JTextField("text 3"));
        panel.add(new JTextField("text 4"));

        // You have to work with your container
        // the has the 74 fields. I created this 
        // panel just to test the code.
        iterateOverJTextFields(panel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! God bless you

Comment: Please notice, it is possible to get any type of the component in this way :)